# Only let users input positive integers (no decimals or strings)?

Tags: java, string, input, integer

I know how to ask the user to input positive integers, but I don't know how approach the code to avoid an input error such as a decimal or string input.

```
  int seedValue;
  double angle, gunpowder;

  System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer seed value: ");
  seedValue = input.nextInt();

     while (seedValue <= 0) {  
        System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer seed value: ");
        seedValue = input.nextInt();
     }

     System.out.println("That target is " +
      threeDec.format(gen.nextDouble() * 1000) + "m away.");
```

Comment: As a side-note, you don't need that first input section `println(...` and `seedValue = ...`. The one inside the loop is enough.

Comment: @Tharwen: As long as you initialize `seedValue` to something negative, or use a `do`...`while` loop instead.  Otherwise, either Java will complain about you using an uninitialized value, or the loop will never run.

Comment: Doesn't Java initialise ints to 0?

Comment: @Tharwen: For class and instance variables, yes.  But locals, no -- Java won't initialize them (JLS7, §4.12.3/7), and the compiler won't let you read them til it sees you've definitely assigned a value for them (§16).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This may be an approch:

- Read the input as a `string` value using `Scanner.readLine();`
- Try to convert the string to int using `Integer.parseInt` method. This method will throw a `NumberFormatException` in case the input string contains decimals and invalid digits.
- if the input value is parsed properly in previous step, then check for negative

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer seed value: ");
boolean flag = true;
while(flag) {
  try {
    seedValue = Integer.valueOf(input.nextLine());
    if (seedValue <= 0) {
      System.out.println("input is not a positive Integer ");
      System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer seed value: ");
    } else {
      flag=false;
    }
  } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
      System.out.println("input is not a positive Integer ");
      System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer seed value: ");
  }

}
```

Comment: There are far better ways to accomplish this.

Comment: I don't think there's anything you can really change that will add value to this thread at this point.

Comment: @redFIVE : you are probably right.. but it gives us no reason to stop improving a bad answer does it mate.? ;)

Comment: If i were going to do something like this, i'd (a) get rid of the flag, changing `while(flag)` to `while (true)` and `flag=false;` to `break;`, (b) throw an exception when `seedValue <= 0`, so the exception handler is the only thing complaining about invalid input, and (c) move the prompt to just before the input, so it doesn't have to be repeated everywhere.  But i probably wouldn't do this; there really are much cleaner ways.

Comment: Actually, a `do...while` would remove the need for the `break` entirely.  Pseudocode: `do { show prompt; get input; try { convert; } catch { input = -1; } if input <= 0 then print error message; } while input <= 0;`

Comment: @cHao : cleaner and nicer solution +1 for getting rid of the `flag`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that "input" is the Scanner class. If so, check out the javadoc for the Scanner.nextInt() method. It throws a number of exceptions if an integer is not entered. So you should put your call to it in a try catch block and look for these exceptions. The next thing you can do since that still lets them enter a negative value is simply check if the input is less than 0 and if so, output some message letting the user know they must only enter a positive value.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt looks fine, you let the user type something in and then check if it matches the required form. If not, proceed in asking the user again or output an error or whatever. If you want to make the program in a way, that letters, like the '-' char don't even appear on the screen while typing in, you still have to read whatever the user typed in, validate it, reform the string (delete the illegal letter) and refresh the screen with every single keystroke happening. This is probably not what should be done here.

Imagine your common social websites while creating a profile with password requirements like having one number, at least 6 letters and so on. You can type whatever you want in the textbox, only after submitting the form the program either accepts your input or redirects you to the same form with an error message to hint at the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what class `input` is exactly, but I presume its `Scanner` reading from standard in. If this is the case, you can take advantage of the exceptions thrown by `nextInt()`, specifically `InputMismatchException`. Your code would be -

```
int seedValue;
double angle, gunpowder;

System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer seed value: ");
while(invalidInput){
   try{
     seedValue = input.nextInt();
     if(seedValue <= 0) {  
            System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer seed value: ");
     }
     else{invalidInput=false;}
   }
   catch(InputMismatchException e){
        System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer seed value: ");
   }
```

}

```
     System.out.println("That target is " +
      threeDec.format(gen.nextDouble() * 1000) + "m away.");
```

Comment: if the user enters an alphabet your code goes into an infinite loop

Comment: No it doesn't. If you enter an alphabetic input you trigger the catch block. This causes another prompt and a (proper) restart of the loop

Comment: it is not because of the exit condition, it is because of the Scanner... when nextInt() throw an exception the scanner is not moved, it just keeps on sending the same input again from the same location forming an infinite loop throwing InputMismatchException. a better solution would be is to use Integer.valueOf(input.nextLine()) and use a NumberFormatException in the catch clause

Comment: no it does go into an infinite loop... check my above comment